# Real world usage of information inside /proc

Tags: linux, proc

As preparation for the LPI 1 certification, I am beginning to go through the list of objectives in exam 101. After reviewing **/proc**, I understand that programs like `ps`, `free`, or `top` use **meminfo** and **cpuinfo**.

However, I still do not see a practical case where a system administrator would need to access the information available in files such as **dma**, **interrupts**, **irq**, **ioports** and others.

So my question is, have any of you used the above files, or know of a vital program that does?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The files **dma**, **interrupts**, **irq** and **ioports** can be important when dealing with legacy hardware, e.g. an industrial PC that might still have ISA card slots.

Historical note: The ISA bus was not originally auto-configurable, and attempts to retro-fit automatic configuration mechanisms to it, known as "Plug and Play" or PnP, caused a lot of people to read the name of the auto-configuration mechanism as "Plug and Pray" instead. In other words, *it did not always work well*. Manual configuration required understanding which system resources were free (i.e. assignable to a new card) and which were already in use.

Those files are also important to driver developers: they allow the developer to verify that the driver has correctly registered the hardware resources it needs to use.

Another historical note: before the `/sys` virtual filesystem was designed, `/proc` was used as a general dumping ground of various diagnostic information, since it was significantly easier to produce a virtual file or directory in `/proc` than to provide another type of interface for accessing the same information. It was there and it was easy to use, so of course it did get used by the various Linux driver and subsystem developers.

Since the introduction of `/sys` this has already been cleaned up somewhat, but because some userspace tools have been created to rely on those old diagnostic interfaces in `/proc`, the progress to deprecate and eventually remove (at least some of) them proceeds slowly.

Comment: Thank you @telcoM! Just what I needed. It is crystal clear now.